# To check whether group is cyclic

Tags: group-theory

Group is $Z_4 ×Z_9$.  Now i have 36 elements in this.  One way is to check order of every element in this and see if it equals 36. But that would be tedious.  Is there any better way?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is a consequence of the Chinese remainder theorem since $4$ and $9$ are coprime. The morphism $f: Z/36\rightarrow Z/4\times Z/9$ defined by $f(x_{36})=(x_4,x_9)$ is an isomorphism, where $x_i$ is the class of $x$ in $Z/i$, the generator is $f(1_{36})$.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem#Theorem_statement

You can do this by hands also. $u,v\in Z, 9u-8v=u$ $mod$ $4$ since $9u=(2\times 4+1)u =u$ $mod$ $4$ and $8v=0$ $mod$ $4$. You also have $9u=0$ $mod$ $9$, $-8v=(1-9)v= v$ $mod$ $9$, thus $9u-8v=v$ $mod$ $9$. This implies that $(u_4,v_9)=((9u-8v)_4,(9u-8v)_9)=(9u-8v)(1_4,1_9)$. We deduce that $(1_4,1_9)$ is a generator of $Z/4\times Z/9$.

Comment: Can you elaborate

Comment: How does this answer my question

Comment: The image of $f(1_{36})=(1_4,1_9)$ is a generator of $Z/4\times Z/9$.

Comment: Is there any other way to do this without using this theorem?  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If $a$ is a generator of $Z/4$a and $b$ a generator of $Z/9$, then $(a,b)$ will generate $Z/4 \times Z/9$. Note that if $k(a,b) = (ka, kb) = (0,0)$ then 4 divides $k$ and 9 divides $k$. Thus 36 divides $k$.